# knockoutjs kogrid display date within cell - with plunk

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, kogrid

I have the following columnDefs

```
self.columnDefs = [
        { width: 150, field: 'timeReceived', displayName: 'Time Received', cellFilter: function (data) { return moment(data).format('DD/MM/YYYY h:mm a') } },
        { width: 500, field: 'name', displayName: 'Name' },
        { width: 150, field: 'LinkToTimeSent', displayName: 'Time SentX', cellTemplate: '<a data-bind="text:$parent.entity.timeSent, attr: { href: $parent.entity.linkToTimeSent}" ></a>' },
    ];
```

My problem is with the Time SentX. I'd like this to display the content of entity.timeSent but converted for human consumption using the moment library.

How can I call the function moment($parent.entity.timeSent).format('DD/MM/YYYY h:mm a') from within my columnDefs?

In the following plunk, line 96 needs to contain something like

```
text:moment($parent.entity.TimeSent, "DD/MM/YYYY h:mm a") but I can't get it to work!
```

:https://plnkr.co/edit/jNn3knbnCCbBQu9NgKze?p=preview

Comment: what is the problem with using the cellFilter like in your question: `{ field: 'TimeSent', displayName: 'TimeSent', width: 130, cellFilter: function (data) { return moment(data).format('DD/MM/YYYY h:mm a')} },
                   ` here it is working fine: https://plnkr.co/edit/sqNyTmm4ZisVg1CzVSIt?p=preview

Comment: Hi @nemesv, I want the text within the cell to be a hyperlink. So, it should display the time sent but when the user clicks this, navigate to a copy of the message that was sent. This is why I'm using cellTemplate rather than cellFilter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** My answer was a bit too general. An attempt to be more specific.

Map your `WorkflowRules` to their own "viewmodels", and you can do anything you like:

```
this.workflowRules = ko.observableArray(sampleData.WorkflowRules
  .map(function(jsonRule) {

    // Add UI helpers (create a sort of viewmodel)
    var timeSentMoment  = moment(jsonRule.TimeSent);

    // Purely for display purposes:
    jsonRule.timeSentLabel = timeSentMoment.format('DD/MM/YYYY h:mm a');
    // Do what ever you want to create the right url
    jsonRule.href = jsonRule.TimeSent; 

    return jsonRule;
}));
```

Then, in your template:

```
<div data-bind="with: $parent.entity">
  <a data-bind="text: timeSentLabel, 
                attr: {href: href}"></a>
</div>';
```

Which is defined in js:

```
var timeSentTemplate = '<div data-bind="with: $parent.entity"><a data-bind="text: timeSentLabel, attr: {href: href}"></a></div>';

var columnDefs = [
  { cellTemplate: timeSentTemplate, /* etc. */ }
];
```

I hope I finally got your question correctly...

(https://plnkr.co/edit/93ucvDLk5bUFtU4dB1vn?p=preview, moved some stuff around)

---

**Previous, more general answer:**

When you create a knockout binding, knockout automatically wraps the second part of the binding in a function. For example:

```
data-bind="text: myTextObservable"
```

Is processed as:

```
text: function (){ return myTextObservable }
```

Additionally, knockout uses this function to create a `computedObservable`. This will create a subscription to any observable used inside the function, making sure the data-bind is re-evaluated if any of them changes.

This means that in your case, you can define your format rule inside your data-bind like so (assuming `timeSent` is an observable`):

```
data-bind="text: moment($parent.entity.timeSent()).format('DD/MM/YYYY h:mm a') "
```

Knockout will see that the `timeSent` observable is called and make sure the whole binding gets updated correctly. Here's an example:

```js
var date = ko.observable(new Date());
var addDay = function() {
  date(moment(date())
    .add(1, "day")
    .toDate()
  );
};

ko.applyBindings({
  date: date,
  addDay: addDay
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<strong>The "raw" observable</strong>
<div data-bind="text: date"></div>
<br/>
<strong>A "computed" text defined in the data-bind</strong>
<div data-bind="text: moment(date()).format('DD-MM-YY')"></div>
<button data-bind="click:addDay">add a day</button>
```

My advice however is to create a separate computed observable inside your viewmodel. After all, this is what viewmodels are meant to do, and it will help you out a great deal when fixing bugs. I.e.:

```
// Add to your entity view model:
this.timeSentLabel = ko.computed(function() {
  return moment(this.timeSent())
    .format('DD/MM/YYYY h:mm a');
}, this);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need to call the moment function from within the columnDefs of the koGrid gridOptions function. I have tried to illustrate in the following plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/jNn3knbnCCbBQu9NgKze?p=preview

Comment: It's not an observable? The first approach I've shown (which is very similar to what you tried) still works, right? https://plnkr.co/edit/131jE4ztY4FRUBRqWr7I?p=preview

Comment: I can display the timestamp in a human readable way. I can also display a link that works when clicked. What I haven't managed to do is combine the two! I need to somehow wrap a call to moment around the value provided to the text binding of the <a> tag: cellTemplate: '<a data-bind="text:$parent.entity.timeSent, attr: { href: $parent.entity.linkToTimeSent}" ></a>'

Comment: I had another attempt to answer your question, after your clarifications. I've edited my post.

Comment: That's great thanks. I hadn't used the .map function of a javascript array before - very helpful!